# query optimization with multiple sub-queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to retrieve data 
number of meters in this month, minus the number of meters in the previous month, 
and the value of the meter is deducted in accordance with their respective codes. 
then summed the whole.

there are about 8000 records.

but I try to take 5 records, and it takes time 2:53 sec, 
100 records takes time (1 min 1:57 sec).
really matter .

I have query like this.

```
SELECT code hvCode,
       IFNULL( (SELECT meter 
               FROM bmrpt 
               WHERE waktu_foto LIKE '2014-05%' 
               GROUP BY code HAVING code = hvCode),0 )
      -IFNULL( (SELECT meter 
               FROM bmrpt WHERE waktu_foto LIKE  '2014-04%' 
               GROUP BY code HAVING code = hvCode),0 )hasil
FROM bmrpt group by code;
```

does anybody have an idea to change the query to be optimized?

this the sqlfiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/495c0/1

best regards

Comment: datatype of `waktu_foto`?

Comment: please create a demo table on http://www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: dont use 'like' if you want to increase the performance because by using like you denied the index for waktu_foto. Format it properly by using date_format function. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

though your question is unclear but try below subquery , as what I understand

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(`meter`),0) FROM table WHERE code ='hvCode' AND MONTH(`date_column`) = 5 
- 
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(`meter`),0) FROM table WHERE code ='hvCode' AND MONTH(`date_column`) = 4
```

Comment: how about the year? I present the data in a month each year

Comment: add one more condition then.